# iTerm2 "bad floating point constant" on startup

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2

I am not sure whether this is the correct place to post this question.

I recently installed iTerm 2 together with shell integration.
However, I am getting a constant error/warning on the start up:

```
> /Users/usr/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh:32: bad floating point constant
```

The `.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh` on line 32 has the following code:

```
ver=$(printf "%.0f" $(sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' ' | sed -e 's/ //g'))
zsh: bad floating point constant
```

[image: line 32 snippet]

I am not sure if there is a bug or if there is something wrong with my setup.

The build version is **3.4.18** and I am running this on MacOS Ventura 13.0.1.

Comment: You forgot to tell us the most important point: What is the output of the `sed`  command? Also, please remove the tags _terminal_ and _iterm2_, since they are not relevant to your question.

Comment: @user1934428 The iterm2 tag is relevant to my question as this is taken from the ```iterm2_shell_integration.zsh``` which is produced when installing the shell integration in iterm2.
Furthermore, it also provides some context to my question. This is not code I have written, if there is a known bug with this part of iterm2 it could help others finding a solution if this problem appears.
And, last of all, there is no wiki on the iterm2 tag which states what falls under this tag and what does not

Comment: regarding the ```sed``` command, I did not forget because I do not see how this is *the most important point*. Why specifically the ```sed``` command? Also, you can clearly read it from the code: replace spaces with no spaces ...
Anyhow, as I specified in my answer, the issues lies with ```printf "%.0f" ```.

Comment: `iterm2` is only relevant to the extent, as you define in its configuration how the shell is started. If you you post the startup command for the shell in your question, the terminal emulator you use is irrelevant (unless of course your question refers to issues regarding terminal capabilities (`tput`, `stty`, `$TERM`), which it doesn't).

Comment: As for the failing code: Even if you have not written it yourself, you know what statement causes the error, so you can manually execute it step by step on the command line. My personal opinion is that the assignment to `ver` is incorrect and that you need to fix this. After this, report your fix to the original developer, so he can incorporate the bugfix into his version.

Answer (score 2):

Just run "Install Shell integration" again.

`iTerm2 > Install Shell integration`

Comment: This worked for me. This menu item is located where the "About iTerm2", "Check for Updates", "Quit", etc options all reside.

Answer (score 1):

The `ver` tries to retrieve your main OS version, in your case, it should be 13.

Try commenting line 32 and instead configure:

```bash
ver=13
```

Or you can fix the line yourself, there's most likely something replaced/new in MacOS 13, so try to open up a terminal and execute these commands apart from each other to see where it errors:

```bash
sw_vers
sw_vers | grep ProductVersion
sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2
sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' '
sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' ' | sed -e 's/ //g'
printf "%.0f" $(sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' ' | sed -e 's/ //g')
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @KevinC suggestion:

Substituting line 32 with

```
ver=$(printf "%.0f" $(sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' ' | cut -d'.' -f 1 | sed -e 's/ //g'))
```

seems to do the job.
The issue is that with non-major Mac OS versions, for example `13.0.1` in this case, it tries to do the float formatting via `printf "%.0f"` which fails since the version number is not a float.

This may not be a solid solution but it gets the job done.

You can test this on your terminal with

```
printf "%.0f" $(echo some_version_number | tr -d ' ' | cut -d'.' -f 1  | sed -e 's/ //g')
```

for example set `some_version_number` to 13.0.1 or 13.0 and it should yield 13 in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Big Sur (11.6.2)

I replaced this part of line 32:

```
sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' ' | sed -e 's/ //g'
```

- which produced the following output:

  ```
      11.6.2
  ```

  - the leading space seemed to be the problem

with

```
sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | sed -e 's/\..*//g' | xargs
```

- `sed` command just gets the major version (`11`) which is all that seems to be needed considering the next line of code

  ```
  if (( $ver >= 13 )); then
    unset -f iterm2_base64
    function iterm2_base64() {
      perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64(join("", <>))'
    }
  fi
  ```
- `xargs` automatically trims the leading whitespace

---

---

---

Here is the output from testing the lines sequentially

```
 $ sw_vers | grep ProductVersion                                                                                                                                         
ProductVersion: 11.6.2
 $ sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2                                                                                                                         
    11.6.2
 $ sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' '                                                                                                             
    11.6.2
 $ sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' ' | sed -e 's/ //g'                                                                                          
    11.6.2
 $ sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | xargs                                                                                                                                
ProductVersion: 11.6.2
 $ sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | xargs                                                                                                                 
11.6.2
 $ sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | sed -e 's/\..*//g' | xargs
11
```